# `friday` package is very slow

Tags: performance, haskell, graphics

I’m writing a Haskell program that draws [big maps](http://puu.sh/mXkbi/ab0d55b7cc.png) from [Knytt Stories](http://nifflas.ni2.se/?page=Knytt+Stories) world files. I use the [`friday`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday) package to make image files, and I need to compose the many graphics layers that I put together from spritesheets. Right now, I use my own ugly function for this:

```
import qualified Vision.Primitive as Im
import qualified Vision.Image.Type as Im
import qualified Vision.Image.Class as Im
import Vision.Image.RGBA.Type (RGBA, RGBAPixel(..))

-- Map a Word8 in [0, 255] to a Double in [0, 1].
w2f :: Word8 -> Double
w2f = (/255) . fromIntegral . fromEnum

-- Map a Double in [0, 1] to a Word8 in [0, 255].
f2w :: Double -> Word8
f2w = toEnum . round . (*255)

-- Compose two images into one. `bottom` is wrapped to `top`'s size.
compose :: RGBA -> RGBA -> RGBA
compose bottom top =
    let newSize = Im.manifestSize top
        bottom' = wrap newSize bottom
    in Im.fromFunction newSize $ \p ->
        let RGBAPixel rB gB bB aB = bottom' Im.! p
            RGBAPixel rT gT bT aT = top Im.! p
            aB' = w2f aB; aT' = w2f aT
            ovl :: Double -> Double -> Double
            ovl cB cT = (cT * aT' + cB * aB' * (1.0 - aT')) / (aT' + aB' * (1.0 - aT'))
            (~*~) :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
            cB ~*~ cT = f2w $ w2f cB `ovl` w2f cT
            aO = f2w (aT' + aB' * (1.0 - aT'))
        in RGBAPixel (rB ~*~ rT) (gB ~*~ gT) (bB ~*~ bT) aO
```

It simply alpha-composites a bottom layer and a top layer, like so:

[image]

If the “bottom” layer is a texture, it will be looped horizontally and vertically (by `wrap`) to fit the top layer’s size.

---

Rendering a map takes far, far longer than it should. Rendering the map for the default world that comes with the game takes **27 minutes** at `-O3`, even though the game itself can clearly render each separate screen in less than a couple of milliseconds. (The smaller example output I linked above see above takes 67 seconds; also far too long.)

The profiler (output is [here](https://bpaste.net/raw/eab52dc7d835)) says the program spends about 77% of its time in `compose`.

Cutting this down seems like a good first step. It seems like a very simple operation, but I can’t find a native function in `friday` that lets me do this. Supposedly GHC should be good at collapsing all of the `fromFunction` stuff, but I don’t know what’s going on. Or is the package just super slow?

[**Here’s the full, compileable code.**](https://gist.github.com/lynn/504e0712b5dd8c13f953)

Comment: Can you use the `-auto-all` profiling option to dig a little deeper into `compose` and see what is taking the time?

Comment: Does this tell you anything? https://bpaste.net/raw/cb2454d6fbc6

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/lynn/504e0712b5dd8c13f953) is the code, for comparison

Comment: This is not why your code is slow, but I'm quite sure you should be able to drop the `toEnum` and `fromEnum` from `w2f` and `f2w`.

Comment: `~*~` operates on two words and should probably be fast and do no allocation. The profile indicates this isn't the case, which is suspicious at the very least. It may be that thunks of `~*~` and other functions are being built by `Im.fromFunction`, whatever that is. Also, the way you test this may have an impact on performance, this library probably relies heavily on fusion and amortized cost analysis to get good performance but this can be broken.

Comment: Switching from `RGBA` to `RGBADelayed` could make a big difference. Can you explain in words what `compose` is supposed to calculate? It's not the most obvious thing in the world.

Comment: Also, use floor instead of round.

Comment: I went ahead and explained in “a thousand words” :) I’ll try `RGBADelayed` when I get the chance, thanks.

Comment: `wrap` is also pretty slow. You can use `fromFunctionCached` to perform only one integer division per row and one per column, instead of two per pixel.

Comment: If you post a complete compileable example I'll be more likely to take a look, FYI.

Comment: @ThomasMDuBuisson, I think the gist may be that. Personally, I'd be more interested in a careful verbal explanation of *exactly* what `compose` should do.

Comment: I don’t know how else to explain. It just overlays two alpha images... I used [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description) (the ones below “As an example”). Is the wrapping the confusing part?

Comment: What my *implementation* does – and I think this costs me a lot of time, but I’m not sure if it’s the root cause – is translate *each* channel of *each* pixel from `Word8` to `Double` and back again, applying the formula from that article on the `Double` values.

Comment: Based on the article you linked to, you might consider pre-multiplied RGBA. This is not quite supported by `friday` so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/RaphaelJ/friday/issues/22). You may or may not be able to speed up the divisions by turning them into multiplications with a lookup table.

Comment: Ok, I've taken the time to build a MCE - which would have been nice - and it runs seemingly instantaneously.  Also, it doesn't produce anything interesting but that's probably due to the lack of alpha in my input images.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, the MCE I made performs fine and does not yield any interesting output:

```
module Main where
import qualified Vision.Primitive as Im
import Vision.Primitive.Shape
import qualified Vision.Image.Type as Im
import qualified Vision.Image.Class as Im
import Vision.Image.RGBA.Type (RGBA, RGBAPixel(..))
import Vision.Image.Storage.DevIL (load, save, Autodetect(..), StorageError, StorageImage(..))
import Vision.Image (convert)
import Data.Word
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [input1,input2,output] <- getArgs
  io1 <- load Autodetect input1 :: IO (Either StorageError StorageImage)
  io2 <- load Autodetect input2 :: IO (Either StorageError StorageImage)
  case (io1,io2) of
    (Left err,_) -> error $ show err
    (_,Left err) -> error $ show err
    (Right i1, Right i2) -> go (convert i1) (convert i2) output
 where
  go i1 i2 output =
      do res <- save Autodetect output (compose i1 i2)
         case res of
          Nothing -> putStrLn "Done with compose"
          Just e  -> error (show (e :: StorageError))

-- Wrap an image to a given size.
wrap :: Im.Size -> RGBA -> RGBA
wrap s im =
    let Z :. h :. w = Im.manifestSize im
    in Im.fromFunction s $ \(Z :. y :. x) -> im Im.! Im.ix2 (y `mod` h) (x `mod` w)

-- Map a Word8 in [0, 255] to a Double in [0, 1].
w2f :: Word8 -> Double
w2f = (/255) . fromIntegral . fromEnum

-- Map a Double in [0, 1] to a Word8 in [0, 255].
f2w :: Double -> Word8
f2w = toEnum . round . (*255)

-- Compose two images into one. `bottom` is wrapped to `top`'s size.
compose :: RGBA -> RGBA -> RGBA
compose bottom top =
    let newSize = Im.manifestSize top
        bottom' = wrap newSize bottom
    in Im.fromFunction newSize $ \p ->
        let RGBAPixel rB gB bB aB = bottom' Im.! p
            RGBAPixel rT gT bT aT = top Im.! p
            aB' = w2f aB; aT' = w2f aT
            ovl :: Double -> Double -> Double
            ovl cB cT = (cT * aT' + cB * aB' * (1.0 - aT')) / (aT' + aB' * (1.0 - aT'))
            (~*~) :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
            cB ~*~ cT = f2w $ w2f cB `ovl` w2f cT
            aO = f2w (aT' + aB' * (1.0 - aT'))
        in RGBAPixel (rB ~*~ rT) (gB ~*~ gT) (bB ~*~ bT) aO
```

This code loads two images, applies your compose operation, and saves the resulting image.  This happens almost instantly:

```
% ghc -O2 so.hs && time ./so /tmp/lambda.jpg /tmp/lambda2.jpg /tmp/output.jpg && o /tmp/output.jpg
Done with compose
./so /tmp/lambda.jpg /tmp/lambda2.jpg /tmp/output.jpg  0.05s user 0.00s system 98% cpu 0.050 total
```

If you have an alternate MCE then please post it.  Your complete code was too non-minimal for my eyes.

Comment: Well, I'm sure composing two images doesn't take long. The problem is that composing thousands of them shouldn't take *this* long.

Comment: So I ask again - care to provide a minimum compilable example?